# Procurar uma string dentro de uma lista python

Tags: python, xml, xls

Ola eu tenho uma planilha `xls` e um `XML` em que eu leio estas informações e o meu objetivo é encontrar informações do `XMl` dentro da planilha para isso estou utilizando o método `IN` mais não encontra

O XML:

```
<nfeProc xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="4.00">
<NFe xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
<infNFe Id="NFe35200915332149000145550010000190821314695600" versao="4.00">
<ide>
...
</ide>
<emit>
...
</emit>
<dest>
...
</dest>
<autXML>
<CNPJ>15332149000145</CNPJ>
</autXML>
<det nItem="1">
<prod>
<cProd>SL-043210</cProd>
<cEAN>6949999876804</cEAN>
<xProd>KIT ONIX / PRISMA 2020 COM MOLDURA BOTAO MODELO UNIVERSAL</xProd>
<NCM>85122021</NCM>
<CEST>0105500</CEST>
<CFOP>5405</CFOP>
<uCom>PC</uCom>
<qCom>3.0000</qCom>
<vUnCom>300.000000</vUnCom>
<vProd>900.00</vProd>
<cEANTrib>6949999876804</cEANTrib>
<uTrib>PC</uTrib>
<qTrib>3.0000</qTrib>
<vUnTrib>300.000000</vUnTrib>
<indTot>1</indTot>
<xPed>2373</xPed>
</prod>
```

A planilha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu já tentei:

```
import xlrd
import os.path
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
#Bibliotecas
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(r"C:\Users\Expedição\Videos\CSV\produtos_filtrado.xls") # Escolhe o arquivo a ser lido.

worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0) #Escolha a aba a ser lida. 

for i in range(worksheet.nrows): #itere sobre os itens da aba 
    lista = (worksheet.row(i))
    print(lista)
#localiza arquivo,lista todos os itens
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#XML = input("Coloque o diretorio do XML: ").strip('"')
tree = ET.parse(r"C:\Users\Expedição\Downloads\35200915332149000145550010000190821314695600-nfe.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

ns = {'nfe': 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe'}
for det in root.findall('.//nfe:det', ns):
    nItem = det.attrib['nItem']
    EAN = det.find('.//nfe:cEAN', ns).text

    if EAN in lista:
        print("encontrado")
        print(EAN)
    else:
        print("nao achou")
        print(EAN)
```

Comment: Esse é todo o seu código??? Onde vc está declarando a variável `lista`?

Comment: a desculpe eu vou editar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está neste `for`:

```
for i in range(worksheet.nrows): #itere sobre os itens da aba 
    lista = (worksheet.row(i))
```

Você itera pelas linhas da planilha, mas a cada iteração do `for` a `lista` é sobrescrita. No final, ela só terá o valor da última linha lida.

Se quer uma lista com todas as linhas, tem que ir adicionando os valores da célula na lista. Eu entendi que o valor está na primeira coluna, então ficaria assim:

```
lista = []
for i in range(worksheet.nrows):
    lista.append(worksheet.cell_value(i, 0))
```

Só que isso também pega o cabeçalho "GTIN/EAN" e coloca na lista. Então você pode trocar o `range` para ignorar a primeira linha. Além disso, depois quando você for ler o XML, o valor de `EAN` será uma string. Mas se os valores da planilha estão como números, a lista terá valores como `6949999876804.0` (que são `float`'s). Então vc tem que converter tudo para string antes de fazer a comparação. Ex:

```
# se os valores da planilha estão como números
lista = []
for i in range(1, worksheet.nrows): # range começa em 1 (ignora o cabeçalho)
    lista.append(f'{worksheet.cell_value(i, 0):.0f}') # transforma em string, sem as casas decimais
    # se os valores da planilhas forem strings (tipo "texto"), pode fazer assim:
    # lista.append(worksheet.cell_value(i, 0))

for det in root.findall('.//nfe:det', ns):
    nItem = det.attrib['nItem']
    EAN = det.find('.//nfe:cEAN', ns).text
    if EAN in lista:
        print(f'EAN {EAN} encontrado')
    else:
        print(f'EAN {EAN} não encontrado')
```

Comment: Olá @hkotsubo eu entendi o que quis fazer, mas obtive um problema ` File "c:/Users/Expedição/Videos/python/Consulta_Prod.py", line 15, in <module>
    lista.append(f'{worksheet.cell_value(i, 0):.0f}') # transforma em string, sem as casas decimais
ValueError: Unknown format code 'f' for object of type 'str'`

Comment: @Vinicius_araujo Então o valor da planilha já está como texto, basta fazer `lista.append(worksheet.cell_value(i, 0))`

Comment: deu certinho muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Tem um problema na lista ela ta em string e vem com o elemento text: antes do numero que vc utiliza para comparação, do jeito que vc ta criando a lista, na verdade vc está criando uma variável e não uma lista. Vou colocar aqui o código de como eu realizei a operação

```
import xlrd
import os.path
import sys
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(r"C:\Users\Expedição\Videos\CSV\produtos_filtrado.xls")

worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(3) #Escolha a aba a ser lida. 

lista = []
for i in range(worksheet.nrows): #itere sobre os itens da aba 
    numb_ean = (worksheet.row(i))
    lista.append(str(numb_ean[0]).replace('text:', "").replace("'", ''))
    
print(lista)

#XML = input("Coloque o diretorio do XML: ").strip('"')
tree = ET.parse(r"C:\Users\Expedição\Downloads\35200915332149000145550010000190821314695600-nfe.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

ns = {'nfe': 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe'}
for EAN in root.findall('.//det', ns):
    nItem = det[0].attrib['nItem']
    EAN = det[0].find('.//cEAN', ns).text
    #print (EAN)

    if  str(EAN) in lista:
        print("encontrado")
        print(EAN)
    else:
        print("nao achou")
        print(EAN)
```